# Magento 2: Hide payment methods depends on shipping method

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, shipping-methods

I have created custom shipping method "Pick up at the store" and payment method "Pay in store" and I would like to hide all other payment methods, when I choose "Pick up at the store" shipping method.

I know, that payment method class has function "isAvailable", but it isn't a good idea to create special conditions for all available methods.

Please advice how I can hide all other payment method except "Pay in store", when "Pick up at the store" shipping method is choose. Thanks.

Comment: Did you get this? What's going on?

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Comment: Checkout my answer below. It should solve your problem. Let me know if you face any problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I tried DRAJAs code, but this does not work for me. The Shipping Method title is always NULL. I found another solution using the deprecated Cart Model. I also tried the new Quote model that should replace the Cart Model, but again this returned NULL... so I know it’s not according to Magento Standards, but it does do the trick for now.

The below example is used to hide the Klara payment method when a pick-up location is selected.

**app/code/Company/Module/etc/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="payment_method_is_active">
        <observer name="custom_payment" instance="Company\Module\Observer\PaymentMethodAvailable" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**Company/Module/Observer/PaymentMethodAvailable.php**

```
<?php
namespace Company\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart;


class PaymentMethodAvailable implements ObserverInterface
{

    /**
     * @var Cart
     */
    protected $cart;

    /**
     * PaymentMethodAvailable constructor.
     * @param Cart $cart
     */
    public function __construct(
        Cart $cart ){
        $this->cart = $cart;
    }

    /**
     * payment_method_is_active event handler.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $shippingMethod = $this->cart->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod();
        $paymentMethod = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance()->getCode();
    
        if ($paymentMethod == "klarna_kp" && $shippingMethod == 'tablerate_pickup') {
            $checkResult = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
            $checkResult->setData('is_available', false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i want to do this but vice versa depends on the payment method show or hide a shipping method ? do you know how can i do it . ?

Comment: I try your code but not working in magento2.3.5

Answer (score 1):

You can disable remaining payment methods using "payment_method_is_active" event

**app/code/Company/Module/etc/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="payment_method_is_active">
        <observer name="custom_payment" instance="Company\Module\Observer\PaymentMethodAvailable" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**Company/Module/Observer/PaymentMethodAvailable.php**

```
<?php

namespace Company\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;


class PaymentMethodAvailable implements ObserverInterface
{

    protected $shippingMethod;

    public function __construct(
           \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingMethodInterface $shippingMethod){

           $this->shippingMethod = $shippingMethod;
    } 
    /**
     * payment_method_is_active event handler.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
         $methodTitle = $this->shippingMethod->getMethodTitle();
          if($methodTitle=="Pick up at the store"){
                if($observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance()->getCode()!=="payinstore"){
                $checkResult = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
                $checkResult->setData('is_available', false);
           }
         }

    }
}
```

Ref link - https://webkul.com/blog/disable-payment-method-programmatically-magento2/

Comment: For magento 1, is any resources available?

Answer (score 1):

Just a note to previous answers. Both are using **payment_method_is_active** event, let's see the code (2.3 here)

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch(
    'payment_method_is_active',
    [
        'result' => $checkResult,
        'method_instance' => $this,
        'quote' => $quote
    ]
);
```

So, quote is accessible through the event itself, and so the **shipping address** (where we can get shipping method info: code, description, etc...)

```
$shippingAddress = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();
```

No need to inject anything extra in observer class constructor

Answer (score 0):

I tried with DRAJIs code, `\Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingMethodInterface` this api always return NULL for shipping method.

We cant use `\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart`, This is deprecated.

We can use `\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session` for getting the current shipping method but Model does not update on shipping method change. For updating session we need to reload the page. So This will also not Serve Our Purpose.

The below Approach will solve the problem.

In order to dynamically disable any given payment method based on selected shipping method we need to use Magentos plugin functionality

Create these files in a custom module.

> etc/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Payment\Model\MethodList">
    <plugin name="override_method" type="Bp\HidePaymentMethod\Plugin\Model\MethodList" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"  />
</type>
</config>
```

> Plugin/Model/MethodList.php

```
<?php

namespace Bp\HidePaymentMethod\Plugin\Model;
 
class MethodList
{
protected $logger;

public function __construct(
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
} 

public function afterGetAvailableMethods(
    \Magento\Payment\Model\MethodList $subject,
    $availableMethods,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface $quote = null
) {

    $shippingMethod = $this->getShippingMethodFromQuote($quote);
    
    // you can check your shipping method from log
    $this->logger->info("Shipping Code From Plugin=>". $shippingMethod);
    
    if($shippingMethod == "matrixrate_matrixrate_13" || $shippingMethod == "matrixrate_matrixrate_14") {

        foreach ($availableMethods as $key => $method) {
            // Here we will hide Cash method while customer select any of the 2 of above shipping method
            if(($method->getCode() == 'cash')) {
                unset($availableMethods[$key]);
            }
        }
    }
    return $availableMethods;



}

/**
* @param \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface $quote
* @return string
*/
private function getShippingMethodFromQuote($quote)
{
    if($quote) {
        return $quote->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod();
    }

    return '';
}
}
```

> Note: Replace Bp/HidePaymentMethod with your Vendor/Module

Answer (score 0):

Add this in events.xml

```
 <event name="payment_method_is_active">
        <observer name="disable_po" instance="Dev14\Replacements\Observer\PaymentMethod" />
    </event>
```

and in file use this code

```
<?php
namespace Dev14\Replacements\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class PaymentMethod implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_appState;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\State $appState,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
        $this->_appState = $appState;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $result = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
        $method_instance = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance();
        $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
        if(null !== $quote){
            if($method_instance->getCode() =='cashondelivery')
            {
                $result->setData('is_available',false);
            }
        }


    }

}
```